# Testing reducer using Jest receiving state prefixed with "0": {before the actual state}

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

So, I was working with Jest to test the reducer and I'm getting the following error

Jest error:

> Expected: [{"assignedfrom": "", "isLoggedIn": false, "username": ""},
> {"assignedfrom": "test"}]
>
> Received: {"0": {"assignedfrom": "", "isLoggedIn": false, "username": ""}, "assignedfrom": "test"}

Note: 0 is being added irrespective of the case/action type

My Reducer:

```
 switch (action.type) {
       case "login":
                return { 
                    ...state,
                username: action.payload.username,
                isLoggedIn:action.payload.isLoggedIn
                }

        case "logout":
            return{
                ...state,
                username:action.payload.username,
                isLoggedIn:action.payload.isLoggedIn
            }  
            
        case "assign":
            return{
                ...state,
                assignedfrom:action.payload.assignedfrom
            }    
        case "removeassign":
            return{
                ...state,
                assignedfrom:action.payload.assignedfrom
            }
        
        default:
           return state;
   }
```

Jest Test:

```
it('should return assignedRN ', () => {
        expect(
            loggedReducer(
              [
                {
                  username: '',
                  isLoggedIn: false,  // initial state
                  assignedfrom: ''
                }
              ],
              {
                type: 'assign',
                payload:{
                    assignedfrom:'test' //action
                }
              }
            )
          ).toEqual(
            [
             
                {
                    username: '', 
                    isLoggedIn: false, 
                    assignedfrom: ''
                },
            {
            assignedfrom: 'test'
            }
        ])
        })
```

If I change the test like this, it is getting passed:

```
 it('should return assignedRN ', () => {
        expect(
            loggedReducer(
              [
                {
                  username: '',
                  isLoggedIn: false,
                  assignedfrom: ''
                }
              ],
              {
                type: 'assign',
                payload:{
                    assignedfrom:'test'
                }
              }
            )
          ).toEqual(
            {
            '0': 
                {
                    username: '', 
                    isLoggedIn: false, 
                    assignedfrom: ''
                }
            , 
            assignedfrom: 'test', 
          
            }
        
          )
        })
```

So, why is that 0 being added? And is there a solution to get the normal state without it being prefixed?

Comment: Please, provide the whole loggedReducer and not just the snippet. This requires to deduce the rest of it, while there could be something that makes it work not as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the test doesn't meet expectations means that there's either a mistake in tested unit or in the test itself.

In this case `loggedReducer` is misused. It's expected to receive plain object as a state and return plain object, while an array was given. This results in plain object with `0` key and incorrectly processed `assignedfrom` key.

It should be:

```
  expect(
    loggedReducer(
      {
          username: '',
          isLoggedIn: false,
          assignedfrom: ''
      },
      {
        type: 'assign',
        payload:{
            assignedfrom:'test'
        }
      }
    )
  )
  ...
```